# Can we use ords 20.3 in front of non-oracle dbs?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

Good day,

I have noticed that every example of ords that i find is in front of an oracle db.  Can oracle ords 20.3 be used to front non-oracle dbs such as db2 or ms sql ?

Thnx
Nikita

Comment: I believe that Oracle Rest Data Services is Oracle-only.

Comment: @paulsm4 is correct. ORDS (and APEX) are Oracle-only technologies, as they are written primarily in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Thnx all.  ThenI am going about this wrong.  I have some corporate data in DB/2 on z/os, and I have other corporate data in other Oracle db's throughout the corp.  From your comments, I can oly conclude  the only way to get to that data is to REST enable it or front it with Web Services.  Is that correct ?